# why i can't fetch data of preparationstep from https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/yummly2 it shows null

Tags: flutter, api, rapidapi

Please help me to solve the problem of null
why I can't fetch data of preparationstep from https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/yummly2 it shows null in flutter help me please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvqMi.png)

````
# **code**
# ```
# recipe.dart
# 
`# import 'dart:html';
# 
# class Recipe {
# final String name;
# final String images;
# final double rating;
# final String totalTime;
# final String preparationSteps;
# 
# Recipe({
# required this.name,
# required this.images,
# required this.rating,
# required this.totalTime,
# required this.preparationSteps,
#   });
# 
# factory Recipe.fromJson(dynamic json) {
# return Recipe(
# name: json['name'] as String,
# images: json['images'][0]['hostedLargeUrl'] as String,
# rating: json['rating'] as double,
# totalTime: json['totalTime'] as String,
# preparationSteps: json['preparationSteps'] as String,
#     );
#   }
# 
# static List<Recipe> recipesFromSnapshot(List snapshot) {
# return snapshot.map((data) {
# return Recipe.fromJson(data);
#     }).toList();
#   }
# 
#   @override
# String toString() {
# return 'Recipe {name: $name, image: $images, rating: $rating, totalTime: $totalTime, preparationSteps: $preparationSteps}';
#   }
# }
# ```
#
````

Comment: please help frineds

Comment: You should check the JSON response (maybe you should print to console), it seems that one of the value in the json is null and you're expecting String. If your response is null, post the request code here and make sure to post the exception you might get

Comment: recipe.api.dart

Answer (score 0):

The compiler clearly said that you are receiving Null is not a subtype of String which mean you declare your value to be String but somehow you are Receiving null for that simple pass null check into your model class:
change type

`final String name` -----> `final String ? name`

The same goes for every value

for more info check this:https://flutterigniter.com/checking-null-aware-operators-dart/

Comment: https://github.com/Nagendra-SM/demo

Comment: help, please final String name -----> final String? name not working

Comment: I've noticed you only add ? in name value try to add ? after every String and double value and also add ? in the json values.

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)

Comment: please help on this error